# How to prove the equality or inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

Can anybody prove that the following equation is right or wrong?
$$\int_0^te^{-t}(1-e^{-2x})^ke^x dx=\int_0^t2k(e^{-2x}-e^{-t-x})(1-e^{-2x})^{k-1}dx$$

where $t>0$ and $k$ is and integer.
My small numerical evaluation showed that this equation is right.(e.g. I calculated the left and right hand side for t=.1 and k=3).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

BR

Frank

Comment: Any background information you can provide may be helpful. Also, if you are attempting this problem individually, sharing your work so far will help us help you better.

Comment: Can we cancel integrals

Comment: @ArchisWelankar cancelling integrals would mean that $e^{-t}(1-e^{-2x})e^{x}$ is equal to $2k(e^{-2x}-e^{-t-x})(1-e^{-2x})^{k-1}$. However, I am not sure whether we can cancel out the integrals or not

Comment: @FrankMoses Can you integrate by parts?

Comment: @vnd yes i think we can use binomial expansion and then integrate it in parts. But the main problem is how to prove that these two sides are equal or not equal

Comment: There really is no need to use binomial expansion here. $\int_0^te^{-t}(1-e^{-2x})^ke^x dx=\left(1-e^{-2t}\right)^k-\int_0^t2ke^{-t-x}(1-e^{-2x})^{k-1}dx$. The integrated out term can once again be written as an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying integration by parts one has $$\int_0^te^{-t}(1-e^{-2x})^ke^x dx=\left(1-e^{-2t}\right)^k-\int_0^t2ke^{-t-x}(1-e^{-2x})^{k-1}dx.$$ Also, one may note that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)^k =2ke^{-2x}\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)^{k-1}$$ so that $$\int_0^t2ke^{-2x}\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)^{k-1}dx=\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)^k |_0^t=\left(1-e^{-2t}\right)^k.$$